# NSNotificationCenter Code works in iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(didEnterBackground:)
                                      name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                      object:nil];
```

Why does this code work on iPhone simulator but not on iPad simulator? I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on this code. Tried version iOS 3.2, 4.2, 4.3.

Comment: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is available from 4.0. If you did try this on iOS < 4.0, it will crash for sure. Are you sure that you really tried it on iOS >= 4.0?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the clarification. Your precise knowledge made me check once again... and I must say you are right. That surprised me quite a bit. Works on >=iOS4  Thanks a lot! :D You saved me a lot of extra work :D

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Chiefly Izzy's comment, `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` is defined as an `extern NSString *`. It's often preferable to define constant strings that way, rather than as:

```
#define UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification @"whatever"
```

Because it allows you to test by identity rather than equality, because all attempts by the user to refer to UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification will refer to the same instance of it, not just to (possibly, subject to compiler fiat) separate NSStrings with the same value.

The actual value for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is contained within UIKit, so when the UIKit library is loaded the pointer will be filled in. The problem is that iOS 3.2 doesn't define UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, so what you end up with is an undefined pointer. Hence you pass an undefined pointer to the NSNotificationCenter, causing the crash when it attempts to read it.

The smart thing to do is probably:

```
UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

if( [currentDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && 
    [currentDevice isMultitaskingSupported])
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                              selector:@selector(didEnterBackground:)
                              name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                              object:nil];
}
```

So you check whether the version of the UIDevice class on this device knows that multitasking is even a possibility and if so whether multitasking is supported. The standard C shortcut evaluation means the thing after the && will be evaluated only if the thing before it succeeds, so there's no chance of accidentally issuing an unrecognised method call.

Only if multitasking is supported do you register for the notification. This will be safe because the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification string was introduced at the same time as multitasking. There is no device that supports multitasking and doesn't provide the string.

Comment: Thanks. My deployment target is set to iOS3 for the moment. Maybe I could just as well set it to iOS4? Any recommendation? Or else I must follow your recommendation, and change the code as you recommend. Thank you very very much.

Comment: If you set deployment target to iOS4 then you should be fine to use UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification without checking that it exists first. According to the API you still may never receive it, since iOS 4 is not supposed to guarantee that multitasking is available, but I don't think that's a concern if you're targeting just the iPad. I tend always to catch UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification and to catch UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification if available, responding to both by ensuring everything in memory is safely stored to disk.

Comment: You can also check if the address of the constant is nil (`if (& UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != nil) { ... }`)

Comment: code sample provided in the answer won't work on iO3.x 
@greg suggested solution to the check the address of the constant is correct

Comment: In what sense does it not work on 3.x? The notification doesn't exist in 3, and in this code you'll never attempt to register for it under 3.